# Create a centered card with an image straddling the left border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a card centered on top of the screen with an image straddling the left border in HTML/CSS. Here is the expected result:

[image: card with an image straddling the left border]

I prepared the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/United-kingdom_flag_icon_round.svg">
    Card Content
</div>
```

I'm not able to center the container AND to get the image straddling the left border. I'm a bit confused with `position:relative` / `position:absolute`.

I'm not sure how to structure my HTML. I wonder if I should add more nested containers.

I prepared a lightweight JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/zbtvweh5/1/

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using `display:flex` in the card then, set `transform: translateX(-.5rem)` in the image.

```css
.main {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  max-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

img {
  width: 2.5rem;
  transform: translateX(-0.5rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="card"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/United-kingdom_flag_icon_round.svg" />Card Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't specify this in my question, but the image must adapt to the size of the text, which is responsive.

Comment: You've got a pretty good answer here, @Fifi. You could at least say thanks. What do you mean "adapt?" What you've got above works pretty well across the board.

Comment: @ralph.m, you are right, I thanked him, but I unfortunately erased the beginning of my comment, so never too late, Thank you for the pretty good answer. I agree with you, that's a pretty good answer. My concern is that if I change the font size, this is no longer responsive :  https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/m2hq6okx/1/

Comment: using `vmin` on the image in this situation can create unexpected results.